# PowerShelll script to export a SharePoint 2013 list from different farm in another domain

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to create a scheduled task to export a SharePoint list that is hosted in another domain. I have the username and password for the account that has access to the that list, and I am looking for a script that would export the list using the provided account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $SiteUrl = "SiteURL"
    $ListName= "ListName"
    $ExportFile ="D:\ListItems.csv"

        $Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "password")
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

     $web=$context.Web

    $Ctx.Load($web)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    #Get the List
    $List = $Ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

    #Get All List Items
    $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $FieldColl = $List.Fields
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.Load($FieldColl)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Array to Hold List Items
    $ListItemCollection = @()

    #Fetch each list item value to export to excel
     Foreach($Item in $ListItems)
     {
        $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
        Foreach($Field in $FieldColl)
        {
                if($NULL -ne $Item[$Field.InternalName])
                {
                    #Expand the value of Person or Lookup fields
                    $FieldType = $Item[$Field.InternalName].GetType().name
                    if (($FieldType -eq "FieldLookupValue") -or ($FieldType -eq "FieldUserValue"))
                    {
                        $FieldValue = $Item[$Field.InternalName].LookupValue
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $FieldValue = $Item[$Field.InternalName]  
                    }
                }
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $Field.InternalName -value $FieldValue
        }
        #Add the object with above properties to the Array
        $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
     }
    #Export the result Array to CSV file
    $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation

    Write-host "List data Exported to CSV file successfully!"
```

Comment: The script as is, did not work until I added dlls as descibed in the following link: https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/using-csom-and-powershell-to-query-sharepoint-online-or-on-premise/